# How to sum columns in a dynamic, evolving dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Suppose we have dataframe `series_DF_1`, that evolves in a Shiny App as the user make inputs, that looks like this in one example:

```
> series_DF_1
       Series One Series Two Series Three
Period          1          2            3
Target      98000      96000        95000
```

Or another version of that dataframe called `series_DF_2` for the sake of example that looks like this based on user inputs (it's a dynamic dataframe that this example is pulled from):

```
> series_DF_2
       Series One Series Two Series Three Series Four
Period          1          1            3           5
Target      98000      96000        95000         100
```

I'd like to create a 5-element vector where the position of the elements represents periods (so the first element position in the vector represents period 1, etc.) and all "Target" values corresponding with that period are summed. So, for example, the `series_DF_1` summation vector would be `98000,96000,95000,0,0`; and the `series_DF_2` summation vector would be `194000,0,95000,0,100`.

Is there a snappy way to do this, in base R or dplyr? I'm trying to avoid my gut temptation of a ponderous for-loop.

Here's my code for the dataframes:

```
series_DF_1 <- data.frame(
  "Series One" = c(1,98000),
  "Series Two" = c(2,96000),
  "Series Three" = c(3,95000),
  row.names = c("Period","Target"),
  check.names = FALSE
)

series_DF_2 <- data.frame(
  "Series One" = c(1,98000),
  "Series Two" = c(1,96000),
  "Series Three" = c(3,95000),
  "Series Four" = c(5,100),
  row.names = c("Period","Target"),
  check.names = FALSE
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is solution with a function:

```
library(dplyr) #> 1.1.0
library(tidyr)

my_function <- function(df) {
  df %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as.data.frame()%>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), as.numeric)) %>% 
  summarise(Target = sum(Target, na.rm = TRUE), .by = Period) %>% 
  complete(Period = 1:5, fill = list(Target = 0)) %>% 
  pull(Target)
}

my_function(series_DF_1)
my_function(series_DF_2)
```

```
> my_function(series_DF_1)
[1] 98000 96000 95000     0     0
> my_function(series_DF_2)
[1] 194000      0  95000      0    100
```

**See comment below from TarJae, must add `group_by(Period) %>%` right before `summarise(...)` to get this to work**

Comment: Hi there TarJae. I'm getting `Error in `dplyr::full_join()`:
! Join columns must be present in data.
✖ Problem with `Period`.` Is there another package you're running that lets you execute this function without a problem?

Comment: try:`my_function <- function(df) {
  df %>% 
    t() %>% 
    as.data.frame()%>% 
    mutate(across(everything(), as.numeric)) %>% 
    group_by(Period) %>% 
    summarise(Target = sum(Target, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    complete(Period = 1:5, fill = list(Target = 0)) %>% 
    pull(Target)
}`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively please try the below code

```r
library(tidyverse)

new_df <- \(x){
x %>% rownames_to_column() %>% 
  pivot_longer(-rowname) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = name, names_from = rowname, values_from = value) %>% 
  complete(Period =1:5) %>% mutate(Target=ifelse(is.na(Target),0,Target)) %>% 
  group_by(Period) %>% 
  mutate(sum=sum(Target)) %>% slice_tail(n=1) %>% pull(sum) 
}

new_df(series_DF_1)
new_df(series_DF_2)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
[1] 98000 96000 95000     0     0

[1] 98000 96000     0 95000     0   100
```